# C++ Задачка на возможность/не возможность приравнивания array1 к array2

Tags: c++, массивы

На собеседовании дали задачу, условия не сфоткал поэтому опишу как есть.
Можно ли приравнять `arr2 к arr1`? 
Даны массивы для примера:

```
int arr1 [6]= {3,7,4,6,8,6}

int arr2 [6]= {3,8,5,7,8,6}
```

Из 2 вычитаем первый и получаем последовательность чисел=

`{0,1,1,1,0,0}`

Можно ли их приравнять? Да! Отбавив от него такую последовательность мы получим arr2=arr1;

Динамически мы должны создавать массивы и проверять их на возможность приравнивания.

Если получим разность к примеру:`{0,2,2,0,} или {0,0,0,1,0,0} или {0,0,0}` ,То ответ **ДА**.

Если :`{0,1,1,0,1,0} или {0,2,0,0,2,2}` и тд, то ответ **НЕТ**.

Суть в том, что между нулями должен быть только один островок с числом(-ами), отличным от нуля.

Как ее решить?

Comment: Почленно вычесть и проверить, что получилось...

Comment: @Harry считай вычли уже. как определить островок чисел между нулями? и если он не один ?

Comment: разницу можно затолкать и в вектор,например, может stl может помочь?

Comment: В вопросе сразу же содержится и ответ. Сама постановка задачи является готовым алгоритмом ее решения. О чём вопрос тогда?

Comment: @AnT а как тогда заставить программу выдавать да или нет?

Comment: `cout << "Да\n";` и `cout << "Нет\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int size = 5;
    int arr[size] = { 3,5,5,4,4};
    int arr2[size] = { 3,5,6,5,4 };
    int counter = 0; //количество символов идущих подряд
    int temp = 0;       // подсчитываем количество единиц
/////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr2[i]-=arr[i];
        if (arr2[i] != 0) { temp++; } //вычленение разницы массивов
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::cout<<arr2[i];         //вывод
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////
    std::cout << std::endl;
    //////////////////////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr2[i] != 0) {         //проверяем только отличные от нуля
            if (arr2[i] == arr2[i + 1]) {
                counter++;  // прибавляем если есть идущие подряд единицы
            }
        }
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (counter == temp-1) {    //проверка на совпадение зависимости
        std::cout << "DAAA";
    } else { std::cout << "NOO"; }
}
```

Додумал. После получения условной разницы например:

{0,0,0,1,1,0};

Проверяем подряд идущие элементы отличные от нуля. Далее узнаем, что есть зависимость количества подряд идущих элементов(counter) от их количества(temp). Отталкиваясь от вышенаписанной разницы, например:

counter=1;

temp=2;

if(counter == temp-1) то ответ **ДА**, можно приравнять эти массивы.

В ином случае, например:

{0,0,1,1,0,1}

Мы получим:

counter=1;

temp=3;

И if(counter == temp-1) уже не сработает и получим ответ **НЕТ**